# How to generate views result programmatically in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I'm trying to update the entire result set of a view using hook_views_post_execute. I've wiped out the $view->result array and have an array of nids I'm getting from a custom function. I would like to generate the ResultRow object from this nid array

Answer (score 0):

Seems `hook_views_post_execute` is not the right choice for this use case. I ended up using `hook_views_query_alter` by adding the nid array in its `addWhere` clause.